# How to display multiple pages of text for all screen sizes?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display full pages of text, where the user can swipe right to continue through the pages.

The swiping left and right to change the page can be done by UIPageViewController, but the part I'm not getting is how to display the individual page of text so that it takes up the whole page, irrespective of whether the user is using an iphone 4 or an iphone 8 plus?

For example, if the first page of full text using default body font size is made for an iphone 4 screen, when the same page is viewed on the iphone 8 plus simulator it's only half a page of text.

The dynamically adjusted text size doesn't appear to make any difference to the above.

If I set the text to be a full page for the iphone 8 plus, then if someone is viewing that page on the smaller iphone they'll have to scroll down to the bottom of the page before swiping to the next page (which wouldn't be a good experience).

Does anyone have any ideas? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm new to coding/swift/xcode. Using Xcode 9.3.1

Attached is the same text using default body font size viewed as iphone 5s and then as iphone 8 plus.

Thanks
[iphone 5s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzXC1.png)
[iphone 8 plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5rZg.png)

Answer (score 0):

take your lbl on a view controller with 0,0,0,0 from all sides and make number of line 0 and in code you can do

```
lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

that will adjust your font size according to yoour screen size

Comment: if this answer helped you @user67478 then plz vote for my answer